# Python Django Smart Select don't work

Tags: python, django, select, django-models, django-forms

I'm a beginner in web dev and I really need help this time because I use Django, I have a problem with smart select. I use this package to permit the user to select a city who depend on the country.
I already installed and I did like he said and it works in the admin page but unfortunately, when I went to my website, they don't work

model.py:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    def __unicode__(self):
        "pour retourner Site"
        return self.continent

class Country (models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)        
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country


class Site(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adresseSt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Continent, default=1 )
    ville = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        chained_field="country", 
        chained_model_field="continent", 
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True
    )      
    codePostale = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

    siege = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    telephone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True,blank = True)
    fax = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    Correspondant = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    secteur = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    codeClient = models.ForeignKey('Client')
    contact = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True, null=True, through='Emploi')

    def __unicode__(self):
        "pour retourner Site"
        adresse = self.nom
        return adresse
```

views.py:

```
class SiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        exclude = ['siege' ,'contact']


def ajouterSt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SiteForm(request.POST or None)  
        if form.is_valid(): 
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            return render(request, 'gestion/home.html')     
    else:
        form = SiteForm() 
    return render(request, 'gestion/ajouterSt.html', locals())
```

and Template : ajouterSt

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
        <h2> formulaire </h2>

        <form action="/ajouterSt/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Norman8054 i get no error but when i have the ville field empty even when i choose a country :( in admin page it work fine but when i use it in my form , it don't work

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to implement some javascript to your webpage. Compare to the working admin page. Which javascript files are loaded there? Do you load them on your page too?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - MAY- 2017**

Sorry, things have a bit changed as of now, my form also refused to load and yet it was loading some time back, so you have to include the tag below, right after the **jquery** and the tag that contains **chainedfk.js**

This works very well both for django 1.10.5 and Django 1.11 -(the latest version as of this writting)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js' %}"></script>
```